# Hera 5.1.3 Conky Scripts and Cairo-dock Switcher disappear when switching desktops

Tags: release-hera

I just upgraded to Hera 5.1.3.  My Conky Scripts and Cairo-dock Swither worked fine and were visible on all desktops in version 5.1.2 and before.  Now, after reboot, conky scripts and switcher visible on first desktop appearing.  When I switch to another desktop, the conky scripts and switch disappear, even when going back to the original desktop.

Comment: I tried an earlier kernel along with Hera 5.1.3.  the bug happened there as well, so the problem must be with the Hera 5.1.3 code.

Comment: I checked background processes, and the conky scripts are running.  You just can't see them on the desktops.  I ended all of the conky processes, then fired up conky manager and the scripts.  They started, were visitble on the desktop where I launched conky manager.  They switched desktops and the scripts disappeared again, on all desktops.

Comment: When I put the cairo-dock switcher back onto the main cairo-dock, the switcher remains visible and functioning when I switch desktops.

Comment: I have 2 workstations running EOS Hera 5.1.3 and the same situation described above happens exactly the same on both workstations.

Comment: One of the most recent updates fixed the problems.  Conky scripts seen on all workspaces now.